# Menu não fixa no topo ao carregar a página com o scroll no meio da Página

Tags: html, jquery

Então, estou com um problema e ando quebrando a cabeça. 
Fiz um menu superior, no qual ficam as redes social e um segundo menu abaixo com os itens do site.

O problema é que eu fiz com que quando o scroll seja maior que 0, o primeiro menu desapareça e o segundo menu fique fixo no topo. E quando o scroll volte a ser 0, o primeiro menu volte a aparecer.

Até ai tudo bem, está funcionando perfeitamente. O problema é que quando eu atualizo a página com um scroll maior que 0 (No meio do site por exemplo) o primeiro menu não aparece (isso é o certo) e o segundo menu não carrega fixo no topo (esse é o problema), e sim carrega na posição que ele deveria iniciar quando carregamos a página com scroll igual a 0.

Vou mostrar um print do site de quando se carrega o site com scroll 0 e quando se carrega a página com scroll maior que 0.

[image: Scroll igual a 0]

[image: Scroll maior que zero]

Na segunda imagem, era para o menu de baixo (O menu com fundo branco) carregar fixo no topo.

Vou deixar o Código abaixo:

```js
/* ---------------------------------- FUNÇÃO PARA APARECIMENTO E DESAPARECIMENTO DO "MENU SUPERIOR" DA TELA PRINCIPAL ---------------------------------------------- */

$(function() 
{
    $(window).on("scroll", function() 
 {  
    
  /* FUNÇÃO DO MENU SUPERIOR */
    
  if($(window).scrollTop() < 1) 
  {
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').fadeIn(0);
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').css('position','fixed-top');
   
  }
  
  else if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) 
  {
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').fadeOut(0);
   
   
  }
    
  
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="cabecalho-superior">
      
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="cabecalho-superior-acerto">
       
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-5" id="div-redes">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesFace.png"></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesInsta.png"></a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jca-contadores-406/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesLink.png"></a>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLb6KnKGdjKh-usDWdZ93yg?view_as=subscriber" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesYouTube.png"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7" id="div-menu">
         <ul class="" id="ul-cabecalho-superior-direita">
          <li><a href="https://encurtador.com.br/gOPZ6" target="_blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-zap.png"> Whatsapp </a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:contato@jcacontadores.com.br"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-email.png"> contato@jcacontadores.com.br</a></li>
          <li><a class="estilo-botoes" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="font-family: Franklin Gothic; font-size: 100%">Fale com um Especialista</button></a></li>
         </ul>  
        </div>
        
       </div> 
      
     </div>
        
    <!-- ÁREA DOS MENUS SUPERIORES -->
   
     <nav class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="nav-principal">
     
      <div class="visible-xs col-xs-12">
       <a href="index.php"><img src="_imagens/logo-216x93.png" style="width:20%"></a>
      </div>
            
     
     
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="acerto-margin-menu-movel">
      
       <div class="hidden-xs">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="_imagens/logo-216x93.png"></a>
       </div>
       
       <ul id="menu-desktop">
        <li><a href="area-cliente.php" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-right: 0.5% font-family: Franklin Gothic; font-size: 90%" id="bot-area-cliente"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>&nbsp ÁREA DO CLIENTE</button></a></li>
       </ul>
       
       <ul id="menu-desktop">
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-home"><a class="a-menu" href="index.php" style="font-weight: bold;">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-sobre"><a class="a-menu" href="quemsomos.php" style="font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer" id="botao-quemsomos">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
                        
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-servicos" role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle a-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-weight: bold;">
            SERVIÇOS<span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="submenu-servicos">
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-fiscal.php">GESTÃO FISCAL E TRIBUTÁRIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-departamento-pessoal.php">DEPARTAMENTO PESSOAL</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-contabilidade.php">SERVIÇOS CONTÁBEIS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-auditoria.php">AUDITORIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-consultoria.php">CONSULTORIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-incentivos-fiscais.php">BENEFÍCIOS FISCAIS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-area-societaria-legalizacao.php">LEGALIZAÇÃO DE EMPRESAS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-analise-de-produtos.php">ANÁLISE CADASTRAL DE PRODUTOS</a></li>
          </ul>
                   
        </li>
                      
        
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-carreiras" role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle a-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-weight: bold;">
          CARREIRAS<span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="submenu-carreiras">
            <li class="li-submenu-carreiras"><a class="a-submenu-carreiras" href="contato-despertando.php">PROGRAMA DESPERTANDO TALENTOS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-carreiras"><a class="a-submenu-carreiras" href="contato-profissionais.php">PROGRAMA PROFISSIONAIS EXPERIENTES</a></li>
            
          </ul>
                         
        </li>
        
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-blog"><a class="a-menu" href="http://jcacontadores.com.br/" target="blank" style="font-weight: bold;">BLOG</a></li>
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-contato"><a class="a-menu" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato" style="font-weight: bold;">CONTATO</a></li>
       </ul>  
       
                      
              
      </div> 
           
     </nav>
```

O endereço do site caso queiram testar [inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://thiagopetherson.tech)

thiagopetherson.tech

Agradeço a atenção e espero ter sido claro (Sou novo aqui). 
Obrigado !

Comment: Adiciona um trigger no mesmo evento window: `$(window).on("scroll", function(){ // códigos }).trigger("scroll");`

Comment: você só está assinando o evento "scroll", assina também os eventos "load" e "resize". Aí vc  coloca esse código que vc fez de verificar se o menu deve ser exibido dentro de uma função e chama essa função sempre que um dos três eventos for disparado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, consegui com as dicas do Sam e do Sérgio.

Agradeço muito a ajuda de vocês. 
O JavaScript ficou conforme abaixo:

```js
$(function() 
{
    $(window).on("scroll", function() 
 {  
    
  /* FUNÇÃO DO MENU SUPERIOR */
    
  if($(window).scrollTop() < 1) 
  {
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').fadeIn(0);
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').css('position','fixed-top');
   
  }
  
  else if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) 
  {
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').fadeOut(0);
   
   
  }
    
  
    });
 
 $(window).on("load", function()
 {
  /*('nav#nav-principal').css('margin-top','0px'); */
  
  if($(window).scrollTop() < 1) 
  {
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').fadeIn(0);
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').css('position','fixed-top');
   
  }
  
  else if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) 
  {
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').fadeOut(0);
   
   
  }
 
 });
  
  
 $(window).on("resize", function()
 {
  /*('nav#nav-principal').css('margin-top','0px');  */
 
  
  if($(window).scrollTop() < 1) 
  {
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').fadeIn(0);
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').css('position','fixed-top');
   
  }
  
  else if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) 
  {
   $('div#cabecalho-superior').fadeOut(0);
   
   
  }
  
  
 });
 

});
```